create polars array series sharing data with numpy array, with unpredictable offsets
I'm working with "records" that are represented by ~1,000 sample arrays. I have millions of these records, so they take up a fairly significant amount of memory, often exceeding what is available on a pc if one is not careful. I would like to work with polars dataframe with a column with the array datatype containing these records. I would like to have this column share memory with an existing numpy array that contains these records at various unpredictable (not strided) offsets.
In the following example I show a reproducible example of creating python list of the records that shares memory with source_data. Then I show a failed  attempt to create a polars Series containing the same information, also sharing memory with source_data. How can I create a polars Series containing the same information, also sharing memory with source_data?
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

record_len = 1000 # record length
source_data = np.arange(1000000, dtype=np.int64) # all records exist in this array with random offsets
inds0 = np.arange(0,len(source_data), 10000) # temoporary variable to calculate inds
inds = inds0+np.random.randint(0,1000, len(inds0)) # mimic unpredictability of record offsets
# make a python list of "records" sharing memory with source_data
records = [source_data[ind:ind+record_len] for ind in inds]
# confirm that every entry in records shares memory with source_data
assert all(np.shares_memory(records[i], source_data) for i in range(len(inds)))

# make a polars seriesof "records" from that list
# the goal is to also share memory with "source_data"
series = pl.Series("record", records, dtype=pl.Array(pl.Int64, record_len))

# attempt to confirm that memory is shared
# this is likely not the correct test, since polars uses pyarrow internally
# it is likely a test based on pyarrow is more appropriate
# but the question asker does not know the correct test
# test fails
assert all(np.shares_memory(series[i].to_numpy(), source_data) for i in range(len(inds)))


polars works with arrow format internally as far as I know, I don't think you can make it use np shared memory.

I'll edit it to be more clear that it doesn't have to share memory according to numpy. That's just the only way I know how to check.

I don't think this is possible. Even numpy can't do what you're trying to do internally.
Try:
new_ind=[]
for ind in inds:
    new_ind.extend(range(ind, ind+record_len))

np.shares_memory(
    source_data,
    source_data[new_inds]
)
## False

np.shares_memory(
    source_data,
    source_data.view()[new_inds]
)
## False

See this for more info.

Create a pyarrow.LargeListViewArray, then create a polars series from that. except polars doesn't support the necessary datatype, so this doesn't currently work.
record_len = 1000 # record length
source_data = np.arange(1000000, dtype=np.int64) # all records exist in this array with unpredictable offsets
inds0 = np.arange(0,len(source_data), 10000) # temporary variable to calculate offsets
offsets = inds0+np.random.randint(0,1000, len(inds0)) # mimic unpredictability of record offsets
pool = pa.default_memory_pool()
allocated_before = pool.bytes_allocated()
pa_records = pa.LargeListViewArray.from_arrays(offsets, [record_len]*len(offsets), source_data)
allocation_increased = pool.bytes_allocated()-allocated_before

# test memory is shared
#1. less memory allocated than needed to copy
assert allocation_increased<(len(offsets)*record_len)
#2. buffer points to same memory as source_data
assert(pa_records.buffers()[4].address==source_data.ctypes.data)

# throws error "ComputeError('The datatype "+vL" is still not supported in Rust implementation')"
series = pl.Series("record", pa_records)

